Como Escribir en una Columna y fila especifica
Estoy usando Pandas, estoy capturando un archivo csv que le suben desde un input file, al capturar ese csv lee sus datos y organiza los datos de la  manera que quiero
ahora mi pregunta es como puedo escribir en indices especificos y de celdas especificas tambien
el ejemplo al que quiero llegar seria algo asi como este ejemplo que escribi en excel, si se fijan en la imagen ven que desde la columnaNombre1 hasta la 5 hasta alli es como mis datos estarian organizados, ahora si quiero dejar como espacio el indice 1 y 2, para poner el siguiente valor cosa como item  valor luego en otra celda pero en el mismo indice pongo Fecha y su valor que seria una fecha,
https://imgur.com/a/tJmGpod
lo que hice hasta ahora es definir el DataFrame y el componente que tiene la definicion que organiza el data frame y expulsa el resultado para luego ser mandado a escribir en memoria


buffer = BytesIO()


with pd.ExcelWriter(buffer, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df_example_process.to_excel(writer, startrow=2,  sheet_name='AMZ Data', index=False)


buffer.seek(0)



el problema que yo veo tambien es que justamente lo que primero ocurre son las modificaciones y organizacion que mi componente df_example_process pero despues cuando se esta grabando en memoria es que hace el espacio de los indice 1 y 2, ahora en pandas como puedo hacerlo? mientras estoy manipulando el data frame, estaba viendo la documentacion y me encontre con una propiedad df.at[]  en donde le indicas el indice y columna pero esto no me esta funcionando como yo busco
